# I'm looking for a way to texturing using only texture. (no mesh)

Tags: texturing

I am practicing while bringing game characters to Blender.

Because it is a customizable game character, eyelashes, eyebrows, etc. have no mesh but only texture.

So I'm just looking at texturing with texture.

Are there any related tutorials?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to know how to use the UV/2D Image Editor for painting textures without importing the mesh? This is a large area to cover and a few tutorials will only begin to explain the tools. Search for Texture Paint and see what tutorials might be similar to what you are needing to do.

Comment: There is also the Displacement Modifier that can use a texture to define geometry and bump/height/normal maps that fake the geometry.